# Image error handler works on some images but not others

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following to load a placeholder for missing images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.p-box img').one('error', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.perfectly-valid-domain/placeholder.jpg');
  });
});
```

and here's the odd part -- its replacing some of the missing images but not all. I've verified that its not a selector issue by adding:

```
console.log( $('.p-box img') );
```

and its selecting all the proper images … but for whatever reason only performing the replacement on some of them.

Comment: What does the generated source look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Mrchief I got pointed in the right direction; I realized that all I had to do is set the image source to itself after the document was done loading -- since the error handler would now be set, it would load the proper default image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pbox img').one('error', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://site.com/placeholder.jpg');
  });

  $('.pbox img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));   
  });
});
```

Comment: You're simply reloading images, which is fine. There could be side effects but I don't see them affecting you in anyway, so I guess this is fine. Also, as a best practice, you should update your post with the solution instead of answering it. Users are more likely to find it at top!

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing it on `document.ready`, chances are that some of the images have already loaded (or failed). So by the time the handler gets attached, the load has already happened.

One way to get around this is to create the image dynamically in `document.ready` and append to the `p` tag.

Something like:

```
var img = $('<img />');
img.one('error', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.perfectly-valid-domain/placeholder.jpg');
});
img.attr('src', 'imgURL.jpg');
$('.p-box').append(img);
```

Comment: Having to create each image tag in a page (actually site) with 1000's of images is ... well, obnoxious. But it did lead me to the working answer I'm posting.

Comment: @Will: Without further insight into your code, tt was meant to be a guiding light for you! :) Glad you got it working.

Comment: understood, but I was also trying for a more generic solution, as I devised, but your post gave me the springboard to get there.